# Service or event?

Tags: oop, linq-to-sql, design-patterns, c#-3.0

What is the best way to go about calling various services that are **internally only** (i.e. no client code can invoke the logic)?

IProcessService - will run various things and make changes to a domain entity, however when certain data changes on this domain entity we want to send out a notification (add a new record to notification table, record the current user and type of notification, and maybe even send out email).

E.g. Add a client, as soon as we add a client - we want to save a record in the db that a client has been added, if we have a supplier confirmed, we have a delivery date confirmed we want to fire off notifications.

My notifications are a way of logging all activity related to the process of a Order...

Is using a pub sub approach common/ event listers etc?

NOTE: I am using Linq To Sql, and a service layer to communicate with my asp.net mvc app, all my business logic/validation/rules etc reside inside my service layer...

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Domain Events](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/).

When you call `client.ConfirmDeliveryDate()`, it would raise a domain event (`DeliveryDateConfirmed`). You'd then have a class listening to this event: `EmailCustomerWhenDeliveryDateConfirmed`.

Comment: The article does go into a lot of depth however I feel it is far too overcomplicated? If i have a simple event lister that runs some code even taking in an instance of the IRepo (save something to db) to raise a notification I am happy with that, what do you think?